# Undefined error code in C# "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'CHECK constraint 'FK_dbo.Costs_dbo.Reports_Id' does not exist.'"

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, entity-framework-6

We have an Access backend (I know, vomit.) with a C# WPF front end, and after making some changes to the modelbuilder to add some cascade deletes, I have been getting the error mentioned in the title.  I need some help decoding what that error means.  And in general, what is the best way to troubleshoot this when the inner exception is Null, and the error code is "Undefined Error"?

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=CHECK constraint 'FK_dbo.Costs_dbo.Reports_Id' does not exist.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c.<NonQuery>b__4_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass61_0.<ExecuteStatements>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<Update>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
   at EOS_Reporting.App.App_OnStartup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in [PATH]\App.xaml.cs:line 80
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 980
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 927
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 916
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Reporting.App.Main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to access to FK_dbo>Costs_dbo>Reports_Id column?

Comment: An access backend is fine, so long as you understand its appropriate use cases.

Comment: Emanuele, I am not exactly sure what the program is doing at the time this error occurs.  It's during the start-up sequence, and it breaks on the database migration line.  From there, I have been unable to drill into any more details.

Comment: It looks like the database schema has changed since the code was generated. Check if the FK_dbo.Costs_dbo.Reports_Id does exists in the current schema.

Comment: @Jackdaw, I don't know how to translate the identifier FK_dbo.Costs_dbo.Reports_Id into something I would be able to check in the database directly.  It mentions CHECK constraint, so wouldn't that refer to a foreign key assignment?  The database has a Reports table and a Costs table.  It has ID columns in both of those tables, but the ID column always refers to the Report table ID.  The syntax in the error is not immediately helpful in understanding what it's looking for.

Comment: Seems that the problem is that Costs foreign key to Reports_Id is missing from the FK DB.

Comment: @Emanuele I don't have a "FK" DB.  The database is named something different.  I wish the identifier was that easy to read.  Also, there's no column named Reports_ID, and no table named Costs_DBO.  But I do have a table named Costs, and a column named ID in the Reports table.

Comment: @jackdaw I renamed the ID column in the Costs table to Reports_ID just to be sure and it still generates the same error.  Keep in mind, the only thing I changed since this used to work is the .WillCascadeOnDelete() property in the modelbuilder.  Edit:  I checked the relationships in Access, and there is a 1:1 relationship for these tables on the ID column.

Comment: `FK` (foreign key) and `dbo` (database owner) are generated. You mention the model builder - that is code first. Then you mention changing tables and columns. Don't do that! If this is code first make all your changes in code and propogate them down with migrations or by other mechanisms. So perhaps EF is expecting the constraint in question, but since you have manually manipulated the database in question it is gone. Generate a migration and see what EF model differences you have.

Comment: @SteveGreene Therein lies the root of my problems.  The update-database and add-migration features do not work for me on this project.  I am working in collaboration with another dev who is the one who has gotten the project this far.  I think I'll have to get their feedback on how the database has been maintained so far.  As a side note, I only changed the column after the suggestion from jackdaw.  Normally I would want to use the code first features, but like I said they're not working.

Comment: The first thing I think I need to know is WHERE does this CHECK constraint not exist at?  The error doesn't specify.  Is this something missing from the code or the database?

Comment: EF generates SQL commands based on a model of all your classes and configurations (model builder) - it does not look at your database. If you go out and manually manipulate the database so the items it built the model on are no longer there, errors like this come up. If you have an existing migration, you can sync with that and see what is missing and remove the things no longer in the DB. If you don't have that, you could start with an initial migration, then go through the Up() code and comment out the stuff that already exists. Then apply it and the next migration will just be differences.

Comment: Another option is to point to a new database, generate it based of your code models and inspect it for differences with a [schema compare tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though this is a bug in the migration tool.  I'm still working out how to get past it, but [this link](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider/issues/35) does answer my question of what the error means, and how to troubleshoot it.

Working on a resolution...

Thanks to everyone for your input.